# Ruby/Rails: How to map and condense database query into multidimensional arrays

Tags: ruby, postgresql, multidimensional-array, ruby-on-rails-5, relationships

I have a Location model and a Service model. I also have a Meeting model that belongs to one Location and to one Service and has a weekday param and a time param.

I need to display all of my meetings by location then by service in a condensed format. My plan was to pull all my meetings (it's a closed database and will remain very low volume) by location and then by type (service), condense them according to the day while putting them in a multidimensional array that gets read out in the view. The following is how it should look in the view:

---

### Tennille Campus (from Location model)

### Weekend Services (a Service)

*Saturdays (weekday param) at 7:00pm (time param)*
*Sundays at 9:30am and 11:15am*

### Youth

*Sundays at 6:00pm*

---

My plan was for output array to look like:

```
array = [["Weekend Services", ["Saturdays at 7:00pm", "Sundays at 9:30am and 11:15am"]], ["Youth", ["Sundays at 6:00pm"]]]
```

I figured I would pass the location to the function and use my scope for that part but I'm getting lost when it comes to ordering meetings by services in the services order of importance (*a Service scope*). The problem I'm having is trying to not make so many requests to the database with if statements. How do I do this without the if statements?

---

```
**meeting.rb**

belongs_to :location
belongs_to :service

#scopes based on meeting types
scope :in_partial, -> { where(level: 1) }
scope :location, lambda { |location| where(:location_id => location) }
scope :titled, lambda { |title| where(:title => title) }
scope :on_day, lambda { |weekday| where(weekday: Date::DAYNAMES.index(weekday)) }
```

---

```
**service.rb**

has_many :meetings

scope :ordered_by_priority, -> { order(priority: :asc) }
```

---

I'm using rails 5 and a postgresql db.

Thank you for the help and let me know if there's a better way than using the array to do this.

Comment: You can do this sort of condensing ("aggregating") in SQL but it's not usually pretty (at least in MySQL, don't know about postgres). I'd use the ruby-core method [`Array#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method. E.g. `Meeting.all.preload(:location, :service).group_by{|meeting| [meeting.location.name, meeting.service.name]}` (swap out `name` for the relevant field, like `title` or whatever you called them), and go from there.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz: Thank you so much! That did it!

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz: I'd love to select this answer as the correct answer but it's only a comment. If you turn it into an answer, I'll definitely checkmark it.